# Assign automatic weights from bones does not work at all for me

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, weight-painting

I'm trying to make the tutorial called "`Eye Rigging in Blender`" found here :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CCGekumdLLU

and it get a different result from the one reached on the tutorial. From minute 15.06 to minute 17.13 the author press `W` and then `assign automatic weights from bones`and magically for every bone has been assigned a small colored area. But this does not happen to me,even if I have repeated a lot of times what he did. Can you explain to me why ? I add a small recorded video to show you what I do so you can understand where I'm wrong :

[video : what I do](http://sendvid.com/k4y75z65)

[image]

Comment: Try using - Pare with Envelope weights , i also had the same issue but it solved using envelope weights , It might work for you as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution : one mesh can be parented to only one object, whether it's Empty, Mesh or Armature and You can't have two separate Armatures controlling the same mesh.

Comment: http://www.troll.me/images/ancient-aliens-guy/this-guy-here-knows-what-hes-talking-about.jpg

Answer (score 1):

To solve bone heat weight failed issues:

1) remove doubles

2) disable bone deformation for bones that wont be deforming the mesh directly

3) apply location/rotation/scale for the armature and the mesh

4) apply the automatic weights

[image]

Comment: hello man,your solutions don't work. Check this video : http://sendvid.com/9wpac728 ; I tried to to the steps that you have suggested...